# Python- how to replace characters in a list item in a list

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner in python and am trying to tackle this problem and just cannot get my output right. I am trying to change the value of an item in a list and pass the item to a new list.

```
mylist = []
test = ['path', 'name', 'user1', 'orig']
for i in test:
     if 'user' in i:
          mylist = 'user' # or i[:-1]
     else:
          mylist = i
mylist
```

any help would be appreciated or point me to the answer

Damon

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: a list ['path', 'name', 'user', 'orig']  essentially changing the list item 'user1' and removing the last character but keeping the other items in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is what you want: [append](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append)

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> test = ['path', 'name', 'user1', 'orig']
>>> for i in test:
...      if 'user' in i:
...           mylist.append(i[:-1])
...      else:
...           mylist.append(i)
...
>>> mylist
['path', 'name', 'user', 'orig']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a list-comprehension:

```
test = ['path', 'name', 'user1', 'orig']

mylist = ['user' if 'user' in x else x for x in test]
# ['path', 'name', 'user', 'orig']
```

Comment: this is a really good example/explaniation of [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you do:

```
`mylist = 'user'`
```

You are replacing whatever there was in that list with `'user'`. So instead you want to specify an index, say `mylist[i] = 'user'`, or use `append`.

This however can be simplified using a list comprehension:

```
[i if 'user' not in i else 'user' for i in l ]
['path', 'name', 'user', 'orig']
```

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension probably the best answer. but since you're learnng, it's good to see the expanded way too.

```
mylist = []
test = ['path', 'name', 'user1', 'orig']
for x in test:
    if 'user' in x:
        x = 'user'  
        mylist.append(x)
    else:
        mylist.append(x)
mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're learning, I propose a solution as similar as possible to your approach:

```
mylist = []
test = ['path', 'name', 'user1', 'orig']
for i in test:
     if 'user' in i:
          mylist.append('user') # or i[:-1]
     else:
          mylist.append(i)

print(mylist)
```

As you can see, I added the method `.append()`, list method that allows you to insert an element at the end of a list.

What you were doing, with the `=` sign, was an assignment: the value of mylist was reassigned each time.

In this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python) you can find an explanation on how to use `.append()`, or you can have a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)